# How to find the solutions of a LP problem?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, linear-programming, constraints

So i have this LP problem:

[image]

And i need to find the optimal solutions of *x1* and *x2*.

On the answer sheet it states that *x1=a and x2=0.*

Now i was thinking of doing it this way:

*x1+ax2= a*

then

*x2=1-(x1/a)*

The only way i could solve this problem as to get the same results from the answer sheet would be by logic. Then if x1=a

a/a would be equal to 1 and

*x2=1-(x1/a)*

would become x2=1-1=0.

which indeed satisfies the answer sheet.

However if x2=0 then it is not the same as x2=1 on the second constraint.

Then i was thinking of doing it another way :

from the second constraint i know that x2=1, then i substitute it into the first constraint to get that x1=0.

Then the second constraint would be satisfied it x2=1 and not 0.

Is this method right? WHat a i doing wrong? Is there any other method ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some way you´re right. But I´ve taken into account that the constraints are inequalities rather than equations.

From the second constraint we know that $x_2-1\leq 0$. Next I´ve transformed the first constraint: $x_1+ax_2\leq a\Rightarrow x_1+a(x_2-1)\leq0$. We know that $x_1\geq 0$. Thus $a(x_2-1)$ must be $\leq 0$. Since $(x_2-1)\leq 0$ the factor $a$ must be $\geq 0$.

To maximize $x_1$ we look at the first constraint $x_1+ax_2\leq a$. We maximize $x_1$ if we minimize $ax_2$. For that purpose we set $x_2=0$.

Comment: Thanks ! then my answer would be wrong if i used x2=1?

Comment: Yes, since you want to maximize $x_1$ and $x_1=0$ is not the  maximum.

Comment: @SaraSaletti Any further questions? If yes, feel free to ask. If not, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: May i use my strategy by going on by logic to solve the equation ? would that be ok=

Comment: You cannot handle an inequality like an equation. Have you been able to follow my argumentation?